# g3dj/g3db model not rendering, obj works fine

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm a bit new to libgdx so bear with me please! I exported my model with Blender to FBX and then used fbx-conv to produce both a g3db and g3dj file, neither of which are rendering in my Desktop project. Here is my code to render the model:

```
public AssetManager assetManager;
public Array<ModelInstance> instances;
public ModelBatch modelBatch;
public boolean loading;

@Override
public void create () {
    ...

    instances = new Array<ModelInstance>();
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    assetManager = new AssetManager();
    assetManager.load("models/test.g3dj", Model.class);
    loading = true;
}

private void doneLoading() {
    Model test = assetManager.get("models/test.g3dj", Model.class);
    ModelInstance testInstance = new ModelInstance(test);
    instances.add(testInstance);

    //vv this shows that it is loading vv
    System.out.println("Loaded" + test.toString());

    loading = false;
}

public void render () {
    if (loading && assetManager.update()) {
        doneLoading();
    }

    modelBatch.begin(camera);
    modelBatch.render(instances, environment);
    modelBatch.end();
}
```

And here are the non-vertex bits from the g3db json file:

```
"materials": [
    {
        "id": "Material", 
        "ambient": [ 0.200000,  0.200000,  0.200000], 
        "diffuse": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000],
        "emissive": [ 0.500000,  0.500000,  0.500000],
        "opacity":  1.000000,
        "specular": [ 0.200000,  0.200000,  0.200000], 
        "shininess":  20.000000
    }
], 
"nodes": [
    {
        "id": "Circle.002", 
        "rotation": [ 0.000000,  0.000000, -0.000000,  1.000000], 
        "scale": [ 500.000000,  500.000000,  500.000000], 
        "translation": [-1241.342407,  9.894826,  1.567357], 
        "parts": [
            {
                "meshpartid": "Mesh_part1", 
                "materialid": "Material", 
                "uvMapping": [[]]
            }
        ]
    }
], 
"animations": []
```

I didn't apply any image textures to it in Blender, just a diffuse white color. I know it's not my environment lighting or camera cause the obj is loading fine.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: you probably exported your model using meters, while fbx sdk by default uses centimeters. At least I think that might caused the 500x (!!!) scale of your model (and probably the -1240 translation). Reduce those values in the g3dj file to see if it helps. Typically you should not have a scale in your model file as it will cause a lot of issues in your game logic.

Comment: oh my god I didn't even notice those values — this worked like a charm. THANK YOU! :-) !!!